# AsyncTask is not working as expected in Android

Tags: android, firebase, android-asynctask, firebase-storage, android-background

```
GetImages getImages = new GetImages();
getImages.execute(keys);
```

```
    private class GetImages extends AsyncTask(String, Void, Void){



            @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(String... keys) {
                    for(String key : keys){
                        StorageReference referenceImage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/"+key);
                        final long ONE_MB = 1024*1024;
                        referenceImage.getBytes(ONE_MB).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success to Load Bitmap ....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
                            }
                       });
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Completed  All   Tasks ............",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }
        }
```

The problem with the code is that the `AsyncTask` executes `onPostExecute()` before completeing `doInBackGround()` . **Completed All Tasks ...** toast is showing before **Success to load bitmap** toast . I could not understand what the problem is .

Comment: Did you try to delete ` return null;` ?

Comment: you are returning null for result and getting void in your postExceute. ?

Comment: why do you show toast in doInBackground. Use logs

Comment: I think `doInBackground(String... keys)` is getting called but your `OnSuccessListener`'s `onSuccess()` method is not getting called. Can you verify by putting some log inside `doInBackground(String... keys)` method?

Comment: Firebase operations are already asynchronous. You don't need to put them in an `AsyncTask`. That's also why `onPostExecute()` is running before the `OnSuccessListener`.

Comment: @MikeM. Please check the updated question . I know the code is wrong . But I want to perform few operations after all images loads . Give me solutions

Comment: Well, sticking all of those operations in an `AsyncTask` won't accomplish that. You should add the relevant Firebase tags to your question so the users proficient with that API will be more likely to see your question. There might already be some built-in mechanism to do that easily.

Comment: Ok . I have updated the tags .

Answer (score 1):

Firebase method `referenceImage.getBytes` is asynchronous itself and you don't need to put it in an AsyncTask.For displaying Toast after getting images you can do:

```
referenceImage.getBytes(ONE_MB).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success to Load 
     Bitmap....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Completed  All Tasks 
     ............",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
     });
```

Comment: Please see the updated question . I want to perform some operations after all the image loads .

Answer (score 0):

```
GetImages getImages = new GetImages();
getImages.execute(key);
```

Key must init in GetImages class

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Completed  All   Task .......",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Method run after doinbackground complete, you need return flag or data for mark complete method. Do not return NULL

Comment: Please see the updated question . I tried changing the return value , it's not working .

Comment: **Firebase operations are already asynchronous.** This perfect anwser

Comment: Ok I understood that . But I want to load all images then perform some tasks . I know their is problem with my code . Can you give me any solution for that ?